# Excel VBA: Move Outlook email in public folder without using GetNamespace("MAPI")

Tags: excel, outlook, vba

I'm trying to do the following:
I have a list of email that is in a subfolder of my Inbox (named "A_Classer")
I need to run code that will take those emails and place them in another folder.  That destination folder will vary based upon the subject of the message.
I need to do this in excel because the destination file will vary based upon information that is in my Excel Workbook.

So my problem is that I'm using a Windows 32 bit system.  So from what I've read it seems that it doesn't support the GetNamespace("Mapi")  method.   Because when I run it I get an "Error 438" at the GetNamespace("Mapi") line

If the destination file would reside in my Inbox, I could do it but I need to move emails to public folder.

So here I am with my code so far.  If someone could help me pass that error 438 that would be so helpfull.

```
Sub move_to_public_folder()

Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim olFolder As Outlook.Folder         'public folder where I want the email to be moved
Dim sourceFolder As Outlook.Folder           'current folder of the emails that are to be moved
Dim OlApp As Object

Dim myNamespace As Outlook.Namespace
Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient

Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")                         'ouverture du outlook
Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")              'WHERE I GET THE 438 ERROR
Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("guillaume.hebert")
Set olFolder = Session.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olPublicFoldersAllPublicFolders)
Set olFolder = olFolder.Folders("\Q12")

Set sourceFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(sourceFolderInbox)
Set sourceFolder = sourceFolder.Folders("A_Classer")
If sourceFolder Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

I = sourceFolder.Items.Count
nbre_op = I                                                         'détermine combien de courriel dans le répertoire
I = 1
While I <= nbre_op
    Set msg = olFolder.Items(1)
    msg.Move olFolder
    I = I + 1
Wend

Set OlApp = Nothing
```

End Sub

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
...
Set myNamespace = OlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
...
```

As `OlApp` is of type [Application Object (Outlook)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866895(v=office.15).aspx) whereas `Application` is of type [Application Object (Excel)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194565(v=office.15).aspx) when you refer to it from within an Excel macro and as such it does not have any usable `GetNamespace` method

Comment: Tx so much xmojmr!  Worked like a charm.  Now I have another problem is that I don't know how to set olFolder if it's a public folder.  I'll post another question on this.  If you could look at it...  but tx for now anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter whther you use x86 or x64 OS. The method exists in all cases.

The [How to automate Outlook from another program](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/201096) article describes how to automate Outlook.

I'd suggest asking separate questions on another thread. Thus, forum readers may recognize questions and answers easily.